# Unable to use ESRI imagery on MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, arcgis-online-basemaps

I use MapInfo 12.0.2 release build 208. For some weeks I'm not able to launch basemap files example ESRI_World_Street_Map or ESRI_World_Imagery. I receive the below error:

Unable to establish a connection to tile server server.arcgisonline.com unable to open table ESRI_World_Imagery.

Can someone suggest what to do?

Comment: are you using the url https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/0 ?

Comment: Maybe the vendor of these base map services has switched to TLS 1.2? Just a guess. TLS 1.2 isn't supported in these old versions of MapInfo Pro. You will need at least MapInfo Pro v16.0.4 if memory serves me well.

Comment: this is the url i was using in the xml file http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{LEVEL}/{COL}/{ROW}. I've tried even what to sent but it's still not working. There is not another way to have the world imagery with my mapinfo version?